# finally method with try in java

Tags: java

class DaemonThread extends Thread {

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Entering run method");

    try {
        System.out.println("In run Method: currentThread() is"
            + Thread.currentThread());

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }

            // System.out.println("In run method: woke up again");

            finally {
                System.out.println("Leaving run1 Method");
            }
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Leaving run Method");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Entering main Method");

    DaemonThread t = new DaemonThread();
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(900);
    } catch (InterruptedException x) {}

    System.out.println("Leaving main method");
}

}
```

why second finally method not run...as i know finally method must have have to run whatever the condition is ..but in this case only first finally method, why not second finally run.

Comment: How do you expect to exit the `while` loop so that the second `finally` gets executed?

Comment: The first one prints a misleading message. It isn't leaving the run() method at all, or the while loop either: it is just the end of the sleep. You are confusing yourself.

Comment: Good catch @EJP, i did not even look in to the print messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `println` statement is never reached because of the `while(true)` loop that never ends!

If you ever leaves that loop, then the second `finally` block would be executed.

Answer (score 2):

In theory it should run the second finally method, but since it is out of the while(true) loop which never ends then it cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that your `while` loop won't end. Hence there is no question of reaching the outer `finally` block.

Just use any other condition, and you might get what you want to achieve.
For example:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Entering run method");
    int flag = 1;
    try {
        System.out.println("In run Method: currentThread() is"
            + Thread.currentThread());

        while (flag == 1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                 flag = 0;
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }

            // System.out.println("In run method: woke up again");

            finally {
                System.out.println("Leaving run1 Method");
            }
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Leaving run Method");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will never execute the finally block as while loop is always TRUE.Also, from java comments

```
"if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues."
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you expect that on JVM exit because the thread is Daemon, would gracefully exit the loop automatically. That is not true. Daemon threads simply die (at the position in the code currently executing)